# Software for reverse phone lookup

Tags: windows, gratis, android, phone

I am looking for a program that allows me to see to which person / company a phone number does belong to. The intention is that sometimes, I receive calls from numbers that I do not know, and they hang up quickly. I just want to confirm if that number belongs to a company or to someone (person or entity) that it is known for being involved in scams, or if it is a legitimate call.

In summary, here is what I am looking for on the software.

- Preferably Free (paid applications are acceptable suggestions)
- For Windows or Android
- Can list from who is the phone number (at least can tell me if the phone number is from a company or no, and if it is from a company, then which one).
- BONUS: Tell if the phone number is know as being used for scams / telemarketing.

Comment: I've not used any of those myself (hence no answer with a clear candidate), but there are plenty callerID apps available for Android which promise exactly that, including your bonus. For a selection, be welcome to take a look at [CallerID and Directories](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/office_contacts_callerid). // And yes: [Scuba Diving](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/sport_diving) is fun :D A pity I rarely have chance to practice...

Comment: Google is the best solution, just throw the number in there and see. Any app you could find will most likely only work off a single database, that may be outdated or not contain the number. Google will search through the entire Internet and find many results; while most of them are "scammy" and just list every possible number you can often get a real result on the first page of the number was indeed listed in some directory site.

Comment: TrueCaller works for you purpose https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.truecaller&hl=en

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up following Izzy's advice, and found an app called [Reverse Lookup](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.esmobile.reverselookupfree), developed by Nomadic Ratio. It worked perfectly for my needs. It fits the first three characteristics that I was looking for.

It is an Android app that it is free on the Play Store, and in 90% of the times, the app was able to detect from which company the number was for.